# Getting the buffer / file name inside of emacs-ipython-notebook

Tags: emacs, jupyter, jupytext

I'm playing around with notebooks in emacs. My current setup is EIN (`emacs-ipython-notebook`) for interactive support, and `jupytext` for converting `.ipynb` files to `.py`, which is useful for diffs and code reviews. Right now I have to run a `jupytext` shell command to do the sync, but I would like to do this automatically on save, similarly to how `jupytext` supports this out of the box if you're using Jupyter. I tried the following

```
(defun sync-jupytext ()
  "Sync linked files via jupytext."
  (shell-command-to-string (format "jupytext --sync %s" buffer-file-name)))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'sync-jupytext)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as `buffer-file-name` seems to be `nil` once the `ein` mode is activated. (It works if I don't `C-c C-o` to start interactive mode though.) My e-lisp isn't good enough to figure out what variable or code to write instead to get the file name. Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ein uses `polymode` to support multiple major modes in a buffer, and as a result the working buffer isn't associated with the notebook file directly.

The notebook path, which should work in place of `buffer-file-name`, can be accessed via `(ein:$notebook-notebook-name (ein:get-notebook))`.

I think for syncing with `jupytext` you could add an advice around `ein:notebook-save-notebook-success` to sync the notebook (there might be a cleaner way using the `ein:events-on` mechanism, but I'm not sure how).

```
(defun my@sync-jupytext (orig-fn notebook &rest args)
  (apply orig-fn notebook args)
  (message "[jupytext] %s"
           (shell-command-to-string
            (format "jupytext --sync %s"
                    (expand-file-name (ein:$notebook-notebook-name notebook))))))
    
(advice-add 'ein:notebook-save-notebook-success :around #'my@sync-jupytext)
```

Comment: thanks so much! I think this *almost* works. it seems like the notebook path returned here is a relative path to the notebook, starting from the root directory of my project, so when i pipe that to `jupytext` I get a file not found error. I poked around in the debugger a little bit and it seems like all the variables I can find are relative paths. Is there any way to get the absolute path, or the root directory of my project so I can append it to the path?

Comment: does `(expand-file-name (ein:$notebook-notebook-path (ein:get-notebook)))` work?  Is the `default-directory` in the ein buffer not set to the project directory?

Comment: `expand-file-name` indeed does work but not with `ein:$notebook-notebook-path` as it would duplicate some of the path. `ein:$notebook-notebook-name` works though! just to be clear, the following does exactly what I need: `(expand-file-name (ein:$notebook-notebook-name (ein:get-notebook)))`

I'll accept this answer as correct; can you edit your answer with the revised line? thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Did not test this.  But maybe the:

```
(buffer-name)
```

command might work and you could construct the missing file name:

```
(concat (buffer-name) ".ipynb")
```

In emacs there is the RAM buffer and a matching disk file. It goes back to the old timey days where crashes were frequent and they wanted a disk backup.